# Bolacha ou Biscoito?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças, termos

A grande questão nacional no Brasil é se devemos usar o termo *bolacha* ou *biscoito*.
No norte predomina o uso de *biscoito* e no sul *bolacha*.

Pessoalmente cresci ouvindo que: biscoito é doce, bolacha é salgada.
Já ouvi pessoas comentando que bolachas em geral usam massa folhada.

Exemplos: biscoito de chocolate Com recheio de baunilha, bolachas água e sal.

Pessoalmente eu verifico a embalagem, se está escrito *biscoito* então chamo de *biscoito*.

Há outras interpretações que clamam que biscoito se refere a quitutes não achatados e bolacha significa justamente ter formato achatado.

Então gostaria de saber qual seria o termo mais correto.

Comment: Dizes que bolachas em geral usam massa folhada, mas dás o exemplo de Bolachas Água e Sal, que **não** usam massa folhada. Como é, afinal?

Comment: @ANeves disse que já ouvi mas para mim é só a diferença entre doce e salgado. Por isso fiz a pergunta, afinal não entendo de culinária =)

Comment: @ANeves A resposta é "depende". Cada lugar chama de um jeito, e as regras podem variar. Em São Paulo *bolacha* é usado para quase tudo: tem bolacha de água e sal e bolacha de chocolate. Isso vale também para as recheadas: existem as de recheio doce (morango, doce de leite) e de [recheio salgado](http://www.extra.com.br/Alimentos/Padaria/BiscoitosTorradas/Biscoito-Club-Social-Recheado-Queijo-e-Tomate-28g-com-4---Nabisco-10929678.html) e chamamos tudo de *bolacha* (*biscoito* é usado para poucos produtos). Em outras regiões há regras diferentes (salgado x doce, com/sem massa, etc), varia muito.

Comment: @Hugo Sim sim, mas eu gostava que a pergunta fosse clara e coerente com ela própria. Como está, não acho que seja.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### O que dizem os dicionários?

Segundo o dicionário Aulete, a bolacha é um tipo de biscoito. Veja:

> [**biscoito**](http://www.aulete.com.br/biscoito)
>   Alimento assado ao forno, ou frito em óleo, ger. em forma de pequenos quadrados, rodelas etc., que leva farinha, ovos, leite, sal ou açúcar e outros ingredientes
>
> [**bolacha**](http://www.aulete.com.br/bolacha)
>   Biscoito achatado, feito de farinha pouco levedada, em forma de disco ou retangular, salgado ou com açúcar.

E já o Aurélio:

> [**biscoito**](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/biscoito)
>   Bolo de pequeninas dimensões, de farinha, açúcar e por vezes com ovos, bem cozido no forno.
>
> [**bolacha**](https://dicionariodoaurelio.com/bolacha)
>   Espécie de biscoito de farinha muito fina.

Com base no Aurélio, perceba que os dois tratam de biscoito como doce e a bolacha como açucarada ou salgada. Sendo assim, os quitutes salgados não poderiam ser chamados de biscoitos.

Em contrapartida, no Aulete tanto biscoito como a bolacha podem ser salgados ou doces.

#### Mas e as embalagens?

As duas palavras são sinônimas, a própria ANVISA diz isso na [Resolução CNNPA nº 12, de 1978](http://www.anvisa.gov.br/anvisalegis/resol/12_78_biscoitos.htm). A frequência do uso de cada uma é uma característica regional dos estados brasileiros.

[image]
<sub>Fonte: [Mundo Estranho](https://mundoestranho.abril.com.br/alimentacao/o-certo-e-biscoito-ou-bolacha/) (acesso em 21/09/2017)</sub>

#### Onde as pessoas mais utilizam biscoito ou bolacha?

Uma pesquisa no [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com.br/trends/explore?geo=BR&q=biscoito%20recheado,bolacha%20recheada) com base nos últimos 12 meses mostra o volume de pesquisas com os termos "bolacha recheada" e "biscoito recheado" por estado.

[image]

A quantidade de pesquisas do termo **biscoito recheado** é muito maior nos estados brasileiros da Bahia, Minas Gerais, Rio, Pernambuco e Ceará.

[image]
Já para **bolacha recheada** a presença é muito maior no sul do Brasil e em São Paulo.

De qualquer forma, **biscoito** é mais utilizado que bolacha, segundo o Google.

[image]

Comment: Boa resposta. Lembrando que, no mapa, em estados como PE os dois termos são aplicados para diferenciar entre doces e salgados (lembrando ainda que mesmo receitas doces podem levar uma pitada de sal). Já pelo que pesquisei em estados como MG os dois termos são aplicados de forma diferente dependendo da micro-região

Comment: Em Portugal usam-se as duas palavras, mas com significados algo diferentes, tal como definidos no Aulete: a bolacha é fininha, tipo disco ou retângulo; o biscoito é mais espesso e com formas mais variadas. Depois há uns assim intermédios, que uma pessoa pode ficar na dúvida se lhe chama uma coisa ou outra.

Answer (score 5):

Em Portugal usam-se para coisas diferentes.

A bolacha é mais simples enquanto o biscoito é mais requintado, mais próximo de um bolo.

Isto são bolachas:

[image: bolacha]
[image: bolacha]
[image: bolacha]

E isto são biscoitos:

[image: biscoito]
[image: biscoito]
[image: biscoito]